# How to fix the "Unchecked cast" from Generics for different interface

Tags: java, generics, casting

Unchecked cast: 'zzz.szi.m.Something1' to 'T'

I get warnings when I run "mvn package"

```
private <T> T get() throws Exception {
    T m;

    if (/*some condition*/) {
        m = (T)new Something1()
    }
    elseif (/*some condition*/) {
        m = (T)new Something2()
    }
    else {
        m = (T)new Something3()
    }
    return m;
}
```

my class:

```
public class Something1 implements Something {
    // ...
}
public class Something2 implements SomethingElse {
    // ...
}
public class Something3 implements Something, SomethingElse, SomethingMore {
    // ...
}
```

// added casting to (T) but same result

I want no warnings

Comment: Why does it need to be generic?  Why can't this method just return `Object`?

Comment: Are you looking for `instanceof`?

Comment: because when i return "Object" i get incompatible type when i call the function

Comment: @NicholasK no, i need to return an object that is compatible with some interface but each class can implement different interface

Comment: What If `Something3` is passed into your generic method, what is the expected output? Do provide a sample input with expected output in addition to the question raised above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `T` is resolve by the compiler looking at the context of the invocation for that method. If the result of the call is to be assigned to a variable typed `XXX` then `T` would be replaced by `XXX` during compilation to check the logic of the rest of the code.

The question code breaks this contract as the method code seems to be in control of the type returned and so it would normally be incapable of make the right choice in terms of the class to instantiate. That is why this cast is unsafe.

A way to fix this is to return the control to the calling code. For example the `get()` method could accept a class object that indicates the type to be returned and use `Class.newInstance` to create the object with the incovenience of having to handle the corresponding checked exception and the posibility that the requested class does not have a parameter less constructor:

```
private <T> T get(Class<? extends T> class) {
    try {
      return class.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // handle the exception apropiately
    }
}
```

The calling code:

```
Something some;
if (/* condition 1 */) {
   some = get(Something1.class);
} else if (/* condition 2 */) {
   some = get(Something2.class);
}  ...
```

The question remains whether you have subclass agnostic common code to add to the body of `get` before or after the object instantiation to make this method worthwhile otherwise you would be better off simply calling the appropriate subclass constructor within each if-else (i.e. `new Something1()`, `new Something2()` etc).

Answer (score 1):

When you make your method generic, that means that the caller has control over the type parameter.  The caller can always supply anything that meets any bounds, and you have no bounds.  The caller could supply `Integer`, `Object`, or `Foo`, and this method needs to return an instance of that type.

However, that has nothing to do with the conditions in the logic of your method, according to the compiler.  It can't guarantee that what you are returning matches up at all with the type parameter, which is what the compiler is trying to say.

Your method can't be generic here.  If all of your `SomethingX` classes inherit from a base class or interface, then have your method return that type, or else it must be `Object`.  If you need to call one specific method that all your `SomethingX` classes have, extract a new interface and have your method return that type.

If you don't have any common interface, but you must call specific methods on the returned object, then take your conditional logic outside this method into the calling code, or make the method call on the object before returning it.

```
private Object get() throws Exception {
    Object m;

    if (/*some condition*/) {
        Something1 s1 = new Something1();
        s1.s1Method();
        m = s1;
    }
    else if (/*some condition*/) {
        Something2 s2 = new Something2();
        s2.s2Method();
        m = s2;
    }
    else {
        Something3 s3 = new Something3();
        s3.s3Method();
        m = s3;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: that is nice but i need to process data before calling some this functions so should i pass data to this get()?